# Debugging in Code::blocks

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

How to do debuging in codeblocks? I've set few brakepoints and pressed debug/start but program doesn't stop on any of those brakepoints. What do I have to do in order for it to work?

Comment: Could you give us more information? What kind of OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: @Zuljin Windows 7 and GCC 4.5.1

Comment: Is your program compiled with debugging symbols?

Comment: @Victor and how can I check it?

Comment: You can find it under project->build options-> under compiler settings and linker settings. Since you're using gcc, make sure 'Produce debugging symbols [-g]' is checked for your debug configuration. There are also some diagnostic messages C::B logs for gdb. If there's no debug symbols, it would be indicated there.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if u solved it already but i had the same problem and just solved it!!
i have searched *a lot* all over and eventually the problem was....

**non ASCII chars on the project path !!**

i had some hebrew letters on the path where my files are located !!
i changed it to regular english letters and the debugger worked!!

Answer (score 0):

In codeblocks for your program to debug , it should be in an active project .

So:

1. create a new project and
2. add your program to the project
3. Then you will see the red play symbol enabled to debug your program.