# Codeblocks cannot create output directory

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks 12.11 in Widnows XP.  I've been learning C++, so I haven't been working on any specific projects, just individual files.  I'm trying to debug one of these files, but found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107325/debugging-in-codeblocks) that I needed to be in a project in order to debug.  So, I created a project for all of my C++ practice files.  Now, when I try to debug (or run) the program, Code::Blocks gives me this error: "Can't create output directory bin\Debug.

When I remove the file from the project it still gives me this error.  What can I do to try to fix this so that the program can run and debug?

---

Additional information:

In Settings>Compiler>Global Compiler Settings>Compiler Settings>Compiler Flags, I have enabled "Produce debugging symbols [-g]".  This is something that a lot of other resources I've checked have mentioned.

Also, under Debug>Active Debuggers, I've tried using both debuggers, both of which produce the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to remove the entire project directory, create an empty project and then place the source files one by one into the project. Beware if you have a `main()` method in each of your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a friend of mine was getting the same error. So I decided to check it out.

I my case, the error was because of the account user name.

When I checked, the output directory while creating the file and the one in the error being shown, were different.

When I checked, I created an user account name with "$aaa$", and I got the same error.

and I noticed that the error was because of the "$" sign. (Probably).

So, I guess the problem is with the user name. Try changing the user name to something simple.