# Singly linked list's head keeps going to last item on list

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a singly linked list on C++. I am doing this with 3 functions that creates an item based on the structure "DiseaseList", adds that item to the list and then prints it out.

I have been combing this code for literally hours and I can't seem to stop it from positioning the head of this list to the last item. There are only 2 points where the head could change (where head = *) but it must simply be a misunderstanding of what I am writing for I can't figure it out.

Say for example I add two new elements, "1" & "2". It will output "2" on loop forever. Please end my suffering :(

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct DiseaseList
{
    int a;
    struct DiseaseList *Next;

}DList; //Not sure if I needed DList here or should have just used DiseaseList

DList* CreateElement();
void printList(DList*);
DList* AddElement(DList*, DList*);



int main(void)
{
int choose;
DList *Head = NULL, *NewElement;
do {

cout << "1. Add element" << endl;
cout << "2. Print list" << endl;
cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
cin >> choose;
switch (choose)
{
    case 1: 
        NewElement = CreateElement();
        Head = AddElement(Head, NewElement); 
        break;
    case 2: printList(Head); break;
    case 3: return 0;
}
} while (1);

}

DList* CreateElement() //Creates a new item for the list
{
    DList* temp;

    cout << "New Number:";
    cin >> temp->a;
    temp->Next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

DList* AddElement(DList *Head, DList *NewElement) //Adds new item from CreateElement to the list
{

if (Head == NULL)
{
    NewElement->Next = NULL;
    Head = NewElement;

}
else{

DList *temp = Head;
while (temp->Next != NULL)
{
    temp = temp->Next;
}
    temp->Next = NewElement;

}
return Head;
}

void printList(DList* Head)
{
    while (Head != NULL)
{
    cout << Head->a << endl;
    Head = Head->Next;
}

}
```

Comment: Which anomalies did you actually experience when stepping through your code line by line using a decent debugger? Are you sure your signature passing `Head` shouldn't look like this: `DList* AddElement(DList*&, DList*);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateElement` doesn't actually create an element!

This means it is returning (and using) an uninitialized pointer, I'm surprised your compiler didn't show a warning.

Replace this line:

```
DList* temp;
```

with

```
DList* temp = new Dlist;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the only flaw in the code.

Comment: Quite possibly. Hopefully the OP will take your advice and try a debugger.

Comment: So have I just been replacing the same element with the new one, essentially creating a 1 item list? 

And I am using CodeBlocks and the provided Debugger with -Wall and -g. What more should I be looking for?

Comment: It would use whatever happened to be in that memory location at the time, so it is possible it would return the same pointer value each time, which would lead to you infinite list. However, this would depend on what else has been called in between. As for debugging, you should be able to debug in the IDE. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441964/how-to-debug-in-code-blocks

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to @TheDark's answer, you should note that `Head` parameter is never changed in `main()` unless you assign the return value of `AddElement()`, since you're passing the pointer by value:

```
DList* AddElement(DList *Head, DList *NewElement)  {
```

It would be better to pass the `Head` pointer by reference to get it initialized correctly

```
void AddElement(DList*& Head, DList *NewElement)  {
                   // ^ Note the &
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually `Head` is changed because it is assigned the return value of the function in `Head = AddElement(Head, NewElement);`. Having said that, I prefer the reference way as it means you don't have to remember to assign the return value each time you call the function.

Comment: @TheDark THX, I didn't even spot this at a 1st glance. Edited my answer to point out my concerns better.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed minor fixes (also cleaned up white space):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct DList_
{
    int a;
    struct DList_ *Next;
}DList;

DList* CreateElement();
void printList(DList*);
DList* AddElement(DList*, DList*);

int main(void)
{
int choose;
DList *Head = NULL, *NewElement;
    do {
        cout << "1. Add element" << endl;
        cout << "2. Print list" << endl;
        cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose)
        {
        case 1: 
            NewElement = CreateElement();
            Head = AddElement(Head, NewElement); 
            break;
        case 2: printList(Head); break;
        case 3: return 0;
        }
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}

DList* CreateElement() //Creates a new item for the list
{
    DList* temp = new DList;
    cout << "New Number:";
    cin >> temp->a;
    temp->Next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

DList* AddElement(DList *Head, DList *NewElement) //Adds new item from CreateElement to the list
{
    if(Head == NULL)
        return NewElement;
    DList *temp = Head;
    while (temp->Next != NULL)
        temp = temp->Next;
    temp->Next = NewElement;
    return Head;
}

void printList(DList* Head)
{
    while (Head != NULL)
    {
        cout << Head->a << endl;
        Head = Head->Next;
    }
}
```